# Feedback and assistance with MySQL Design

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to improve my PHP skills by undertaking a hobby project to basically build an online-bank(just as a hobby so security etc isn't super important but I will probably include good security to try and build my skills) and although my PHP skills are good some of my understanding of MySQL is not quite as good. I have designed what I think will work on MySQL workbench but require some feedback on my relationships as I am not sure I have done them correctly.

There are 4 main relationships:
A one to many linking Accounts to the user of the Account holder. This is an identifying relationship as an account must have a primary holder.

A one to many linking Accounts to AccountTypes, this is also identifying as an Account can not exist without a type.

A one to many linking Transactions to Users to show who enacted the transaction. This is a one to many and is identifying as a transaction can not exist without a User creating it.

Then there is the one I am less sure about. I need a relationship to link a transaction to two entities within the Accounts table, it needs to link a transaction to the account the money is going from and the account the money is going to. I think It needs to be a one to many relationship but I am not sure. Here is a picture of my current configuration:

[image: See here]

Thank you for your suggestions, I think this is my only stumbling point but if anything else looks stupid/wrong feel free to suggest.

Comment: Any chance you can blow up that image of your tables?

Comment: @Prescott, not really familiar with stackoverflow but you should be able to right click and get the image link and just put that into your browser. It should be full size then!

Comment: Each transaction in an accounting system is called a ledger entry. It records the transaction completely, including date, purpose, authorization, amount, source account, and destination account.  In double entry accounting (manual) these ledger entries were written in the book twice, once under the source account and again on the destination account. In auditable accounting systems these entries are immutable once made. To correct an error requires another transaction. So each Ledger record links to one "authorizing user", one "source account", and one "destination account".

Comment: @OllieJones So should I change to use double-entry as opposed to single entry? That would double the amount of transactions and make tracking them more complicated?

Comment: Double entry was a manual thing. DBMS foreign keys make it unnecessary.